# Jquery .animate only from index page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am designing a small site in which the header will have a different height/position than the other pages (pages X & Y). I would like to use .animate to animate the style change only when the user goes from the Index to pages X or Y, but NOT when the user goes between pages X & Y.

How can I use Jquery to determine which page the user is on, and initiate the animation only if the user is going from Index to X or Y?

CSS, Header:

```
header {
width: 100%;
padding: 4% 0 10px;
}
```

Index Header:

```
.index header {
position: absolute;
top: 130px;
}
```

X & Y Header:

```
.work header, .bio header {
padding-top: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Try to read the page url from address bar

Answer (score 0):

Determine the page you are coming from using referrer and if you are coming from index followed by checking presence of elements that would only be on X or Y

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
   if(/*do custom check on referrer to see if you are coming from index */)
   {   
       // to check if you are on X or Y
       if($(".work").length || $(".work").length){
           // trigger animation 
       }
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    if (/index.html/.test(document.referrer)) { //Use your index page url in the regex instead of index.html
        //do your animation
    }
});
```